# Is it possible to upload an image file using nativescript plugin background-http to an endpoint with the next characteristics:

Tags: angular, nativescript

Headers:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: token

Body: Form-Data
Key: "name"
Value: image-file

This is kind of weird to me because to my understanding application/x-www-form-urlencoded is used for toBase64String uploads and the endpoint is asking for a file with key and value, if you know a image file upload is possible please let me know in the answers, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used to send alphanumeric data, you wouldn't use it for multipart upload.

The plug-in doesn't restrict you to use any particular content type, if your end point is asking for that particular content type with binary file, then there must be some issue. You might have to check with it's owner.